# What is nokogiri % encoding $ character

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Why do I get:

```
Nokogiri::HTML('<a href="/test_$4b.html">test</a>').to_html

=> "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body><a href=\"/test_%244b.html\">test</a></body></html>\n"
```

I thought $ symbol was valid in the url?

Followup:

Why do browsers handle this differently. E.g. In the page: http://www.pmlive.com/pharma_news/its_on_shire_and_abbvie_agree_32bn_takeover_586969

The link: http://www.pmlive.com/pharma_news/mylan_buys_abbotts_non-us_generics_in_$5.3bn_deal_585883 works.

But nokogiri would parse this link as:
http://www.pmlive.com/pharma_news/mylan_buys_abbotts_non-us_generics_in_%245.3bn_deal_585883 which does not work (returns 404).

Are they making the decision that $ is actually safe and a better choice?

Comment: Did you happen to notice how the auto-linkifier interpreted those two versions of the URL?

Comment: Yes, I did notice :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [this RFC3986 here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) which lists the dollar sign as a reserved sub-delimiter (page 12).

> reserved    = gen-delims / sub-delims
>
> gen-delims  = ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"
>
> sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")" / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="

It also recommends how reserved characters should be handle:

> 2.2.  Reserved Characters
>
> URIs include components and subcomponents that are delimited by
> characters in the "reserved" set.  These characters are called
> "reserved" because they may (or may not) be defined as delimiters by
> the generic syntax, by each scheme-specific syntax, or by the
> implementation-specific syntax of a URI's dereferencing algorithm.
> If data for a URI component would conflict with a reserved
> character's purpose as a delimiter, then the conflicting data must be
> percent-encoded before the URI is formed.

The authors of Nokogiri liked decided that since their library may be used by anyone for any purpose, there is no way to automatically determine whether a reserved character would conflict or not, and therefore the "safest" way to handle it (short of testing a URI directly) would be to escape it as per the recommendation.

Comment: Thanks, good answer.  Any chance you have an opinion on the followup question?

Comment: @DuncanStewart although they're reserved, you are still allowed to use them in your URI's as long as they conform to the syntax. Given the context (article titles), they probably decided to leave those in, or maybe they're using a framework that doesn't url encode titles. Which looks better: `$5.3bn`, `_5_3bn`, `53bn`, or `%245%2E3bn`?

Comment: Ironically, the decision to always escape reserved characters has failed in this scenario...