# Why does Nokogiri to_html URL escape differently then URI.escape?

Tags: ruby, uri, nokogiri

Example:

```
URI.escape 'http://www.pmlive.com/pharma_news/mylan_buys_abbotts_non-us_generics_in_$5.3bn_deal_585883' 
=> "http://www.pmlive.com/pharma_news/mylan_buys_abbotts_non-us_generics_in_$5.3bn_deal_585883" 

Nokogiri::HTML.fragment('<a href="http://www.pmlive.com/pharma_news/mylan_buys_abbotts_non-us_generics_in_$5.3bn_deal_585883">test</a>').to_html
=> "<a href=\"http://www.pmlive.com/pharma_news/mylan_buys_abbotts_non-us_generics_in_%245.3bn_deal_585883\">test</a>"
```

As you can see Nokogiri encodes '`$`' to '`%24`' where `URI.escape` does not.

Comment: Your [other recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24878109/what-is-nokogiri-encoding-character) answers why Nokogiri encodes the `$` so isn't this question really why `URI.escape` doesn't?

Comment: I asked the question this way around because nokogiri is the odd one out compared to URI.escape and normal browser behaviour (chrome, FF)

Comment: As far as browsers go, you might want to compare the behavior of [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) and `encodeURIComponent` while you're at it. And I don't think it is the browser handling the URLs differently, it is the server if you're getting a 404.

Comment: encodeURI does not change the $. These other libraries are making an assumption not to % encode the $ and it seems to be correct for this url.  Sure, maybe the server should handle %24 but the correct assumption seems to be that it is safer not to encode the $ char.

Comment: Have you checked other servers to see what they do with %-encoded things in various URL components? This is the web, things like "safer", "sensible", "standards compliant", "sane", ... have nothing to do with it :)

Comment: In my case, it would not be reasonable to behave differently then a web browser.  If the encoding works one way in the major browsers, it needs to work the same way for me. I don't really care about differences between web servers.  I.e. if it breaks for a major web browser i'm happy for it to break for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since [`to_xhtml`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#to_xhtml-instance_method) does what you need, why not use it?

```
require 'nokogiri'

Nokogiri::HTML.fragment('<a href="http://www.pmlive.com/pharma_news/mylan_buys_abbotts_non-us_generics_in_$5.3bn_deal_585883">test</a>').to_html
# => "<a href=\"http://www.pmlive.com/pharma_news/mylan_buys_abbotts_non-us_generics_in_%245.3bn_deal_585883\">test</a>"

Nokogiri::HTML.fragment('<a href="http://www.pmlive.com/pharma_news/mylan_buys_abbotts_non-us_generics_in_$5.3bn_deal_585883">test</a>').to_xhtml
# => "<a href=\"http://www.pmlive.com/pharma_news/mylan_buys_abbotts_non-us_generics_in_$5.3bn_deal_585883\">test</a>"
```